# Calling JPanels within a method and adding it to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing a program which requires input but the input fields are extremely similar (basically they're identical except for the name).  In the code pasted below, I've only shown the code for the first two JPanels but there's a total of 7 of them and, the way my code is currently set up, I just repeat the code 7 times.  However, I feel like there should be a way to write a method and then I can simply call that method 7 times.  Is that possible?  How would I do that?  I need to have panels of different names in order to add them each to my JFrame.

I guess what I'm asking is this: How can you call very similar JPanels within a method so that, upon calling that method, they are added to the JFrame.  I'm a complete noob at Java and this is my first big project.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
public GPACalculatorController(){
    setTitle("GPA Calculator");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel dataEntryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JPanel dataEntryPanelBorder = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel previousSemesterInstructions = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    previousSemesterInstructions.add(new JLabel("Previous Semesters:"), BorderLayout.WEST);

    dataEntryPanel.add(previousSemesterInstructions);

    JPanel semesterOnePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    semesterOnePanel.add(new JLabel("Semester 1:"));
    semesterOnePanel.add(new JLabel("   GPA:"));
    semesterGPA = new JTextField(4);
    semesterOnePanel.add(semesterGPA);
    //semesterGPA.addActionListener(new SemesterGPAListener());
    semesterOnePanel.add(new JLabel("Credits:"));
    semesterCredits = new JTextField(2);
    semesterOnePanel.add(semesterCredits);
    //semesterCredits.addActionListener(new SemesterCreditsListener());
    dataEntryPanel.add(semesterOnePanel);

    JPanel semesterTwoPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    semesterTwoPanel.add(new JLabel("Semester 2:"));
    semesterTwoPanel.add(new JLabel("   GPA:"));
    semesterGPA = new JTextField(4);
    semesterTwoPanel.add(semesterGPA);
    //semesterGPA.addActionListener(new SemesterGPAListener());
    semesterTwoPanel.add(new JLabel("Credits:"));
    semesterCredits = new JTextField(2);
    semesterTwoPanel.add(semesterCredits);
    //semesterCredits.addActionListener(new SemesterCreditsListener());
    dataEntryPanel.add(semesterTwoPanel);
```

Comment: Create `SemesterPanel` class and have one of the constructors to accept `int` parameter.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but, if I did that, wouldn't it name all the panels the same thing?  And if it did that, wouldn't the compiler freak out because I have the same variable declared as various things?

Comment: Define a constructor `SemesterPanel` with the names that you want to assign to the components as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

create a class or possibly a method (function) which accepts a parameter to create a new JPanel.
Use frameObject.setContentPane(panelObject) 
to add that panel to the frame as per ur requirement

Comment: Hate to say this but I am still completely confused (I'm a complete beginner at programming).

I wrote a method public with the following signature 

"JPanel previousSemesterData(int semesterNumber)"

and then in my controller class did

"JPanel mySemester = new previousSemesterData(1);
dataEntryPanel.add(mySemester);"

but it's still not doing anything.  I'm so sorry, I'm just very confused.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.